# grep string when assigning variables

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file in a folder that needs to be removed in order to solve software conflicts.
I know that the folder path of the file is stored in a *.ini file and I want to grep that specific section of the line, have the script to cd into it and remove the offending file.

So far I've done:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

PROFFILE=$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
DIRTEST=$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/

if [ -f $PROFFILE ]
        then
                echo "yes"
#               PROFPATH="$(cat $PROFFILE grep ^[[\s\S]*?(.default)$)"
                echo $PROFPATH

        else
                echo "no"
fi

#script ends here
#
#
```

Im sure I'm doing something wrong with grep and regex by mixing them and not sure how to proceed.

This is an example of the ini file

```
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=l00jsdm9.default
Default=1
```

Comment: At least you're missing a pipe between the `cat`and the `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
PROFPATH=$( awk -F= '$1=="Path" {print $2}' $PROFFILE )
```

or if you have many Path variables in file and need one that matches an expression:

```
PROFPATH=$( awk -F= '$1=="Path" && 2 ~ /default/ {print $2}' $PROFFILE )
```

Comment: Thanks thanasisp
Just for me to understand as I never used awk:
-F = is field separator that separate "Path=" from the rest?
so that '$1=="Path" is the first field that gets removed from the print of $2 when calling $PROFFILE?

Comment: Yes, field separator is `=`. Now `$1` is the first field (the variable) and `$2` the second one (the value).  Then we have the main awk part: `'condition{action}'`. Condition is: if `$1` is the string "Path" AND `$2` contains the string pattern "default". If condition is true, action `print $2` is done. For the rest of lines nothing happens.